# display window on secondary monitor

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display a Window on secondary monitor, as follows:

```
Queue<string> itemQueue = new Queue<string>();

MonitorWindow monitor = new MonitorWindow(itemQueue);

var secondaryScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Where(s => !s.Primary)
                                                            .FirstOrDefault();

if (secondaryScreen != null)
{
     monitor.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
     var workingArea = secondaryScreen.WorkingArea;
     monitor.Left = workingArea.Left;
     monitor.Top = workingArea.Top;
     monitor.Width = workingArea.Width;
     monitor.Height = workingArea.Height;
     monitor.Show();

}
```

The properties have correct values, but  this maximizes the Window on the primary monitor. can you help me?

Comment: Are you sure you did not mix up the primary and secondary monitor? Because I see nothing wrong with your example code...

Comment: What happens when the user has more than two monitors? You just pick one at random? :-( Also, if you want the window maximized, you should just make it maximized. Don't emulate maximized by setting the window coordinates.

Comment: @ChrFin Yeah, I'm sure! I've checked many time :-( !

Comment: @CodyGray my application is not general, and will use for specific purpose! users don't have more of two monitors! meantime, I've set WindowState="Maximized" in xaml code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed the problem with remove the property WindowState="Maximized" in XAML code of MonitorWindow and changed the program as follows:

```
        Queue<string> itemQueue = new Queue<string>();

        MonitorWindow monitor = new MonitorWindow(itemQueue);

        var secondaryScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Where(s => !s.Primary).FirstOrDefault();

        if (secondaryScreen != null)
        {
            if (!monitor.IsLoaded)
                monitor.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
            var workingArea = secondaryScreen.WorkingArea;
            monitor.Left = workingArea.Left;
            monitor.Top = workingArea.Top;
            monitor.Width = workingArea.Width;
            monitor.Height = workingArea.Height;
            // If window isn't loaded then maxmizing will result in the window displaying on the primary monitor
            monitor.Show();
            if (monitor.IsLoaded)
                monitor.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
```